# Python 3.6 based programing implementation to exchange data between 2 modules running concurrently (each one forever)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to implement data exchange between 3 python scripts.
mp1.py responsible to start multiprocessing pipe with mp2.py in order to receive one byte of integer/per-second continuously.
mp2.py holds a data list of integers, which gets updated randomly and acyncrously by 3rd python script script.py.
The following buggy code is implemented in the Jetson Xavier NX development kit and can be reproduced on any standard hardware  running Python 3.6.

Expected behavior: mp1.py receives one byte of integer each second. mp2.py synchronously sends the data to mp1.py  from the list of integers. This list asynchronously feds by script.py based on random timing betwen 1sec. and 1 min.

Buggy behavior: mp1.py receives for ever, only one byte of the two - default bytes of the list.

mp1.py

```
   python

from multiprocessing import Process,Queue,Pipe
from mp2 import getData
import time

parent_conn,child_conn = Pipe()

def getDataByte():
    p = Process(target=getData, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    a = parent_conn.recv()
    print("Recieved Data is:", a)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    while True :
        time.sleep(1)
        getDataByte()
```

mp2.py

```
python

myl = [-1,-2]
mylConsumed = False

def getData(child_conn):
    print("Debug of getData")
    if not len(myl):
        print("myl is consumed")
        data = 0
        mylConsumed = True
    else:
            data = myl[0]
            myl.pop(0)
            print("myl list is: ", myl)
    child_conn.send(data)

def setData(thisBuffer):
    if mylConsumed == True:
        myl1 = thisBuffer
        myl.extend(myl1)
        mylConsumed = False
    print(myl)
```

script.py

```
   python

from mp2 import setData
from random import randint
import time

mybuf = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def setBleData():
    setData(mybuf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        num = randint(1,5) 
        time.sleep(num)
        setBleData()
```

To reproduce the bug:
1st run python3 mp1.py command in the 1st terminal.
2nd run pyhthon3 script.py command in 2nd terminal.

The following is the 1st terminal output display till interrupting execution by CNTL+C :

```
python3 mp1.py
Debug of getData
myl list is:  [-2]
Recieved Data is: -1
Debug of getData
myl list is:  [-2]
Recieved Data is: -1
Debug of getData
myl list is:  [-2]
Recieved Data is: -1
Debug of getData
myl list is:  [-2]
Recieved Data is: -1
Debug of getData
myl list is:  [-2]
Recieved Data is: -1
Debug of getData
myl list is:  [-2]
Recieved Data is: -1
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp1.py", line 16, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

This problem is understood and fixed. Many thanks to everyone involved!!!

The root cause as the described above is improper and not needed at all use of multiprocessing.

All variables and code gets copied to another process address space, hence each process gets stuff done on separate data and code.

After spending lots of hours digging into the problem, the solution is very simple - just import required functions from other python script files.

Comment: Your question is quite hard to understand. You have two Python scripts both running on the same Jetson board and you need one of them to be able to send a single integer to the other somehow (not via Bluetooth) - is that correct? How often do they need to do that? Once? 800 times per second?

Comment: The fact that you are using bluetooth and doing image processing is not really relevant to your question - try and keep things simple and focussed. Are your 2 programs absolutely locked in step or not? I mean, should your image processing be able to run if the bluetooth stuff isn't running? Likewise, should the bluetooth stuff be able to run if the image processing isn't running? Must one sometimes/always wait for the other?

Comment: Both sides are running and perform their required functions (not lock situation). No one is waiting for another. The multiprocessing to receive one byte of integer is performed between the Bluetooth script and the getNumVidi(child_conn) function of the second script once per/second continuously. The list data vidiData[int, int, ,,, int] is fed by the third python script asynchronously by using the setNumVidi(thisBuffer) function of the second script. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: The frequency of  setNumVidi(thisBuffer) call varies between  1 sec. and 1 min. 
 (mostly towards one minute).

Comment: Just missed another answer: all scripts are running within a single Jetson board.

Comment: There are literally dozens of IPC methods available, pick any one that just works on your system. Transferring a handful of bytes per minute isn't really a challenge. That said, it would help if you provided a [mcve] first, along with both expected and actual output it produces. Also, you ask about multithreading, but use multiprocessing. Those are not (!) the same and learning their differences is important in order to pick the right tool. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: We seem to be going backwards. You now seem to have 3 Python scripts. And your code seems to start 9 processes. And more and more stuff is appearing in your comments making everything longer, more spread out and more confusing. Please try to make your question very clear and very simple. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds good, I will re-write and update the question as suggested:  (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve). Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the question, and hope this time it is more clean and reproducible  version of the problem.

Comment: Your `mp1.py` starts a brand new process every 1 second and it's always going to do the same thing - it's the same code. Surely you want to start the second process and leave it running, just waiting for a message, processing it and then waiting for the next one?

Comment: My intention is to receive the current data byte and block receiving  the next data byte till the end processing of the current byte and decreasing (pop) the data list by one.

Comment: This issue is resolved as of today and I've updated the question. This is the first time I am using stack overflow, so I'm not sure what is to be done next: delete the question or update/upload the resolved files. Thanks.